# RemoteDisconnected Error when using requests.patch on Eve endpoint

Tags: python, http, kubernetes, python-requests, eve

I'm trying to track down a frustrating error with my Eve application. I am trying to update a record, but whenever I send the patch request, I am greeted with the following error:

```
 File "/home/undivided/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 140, in patch
return request('patch', url, data=data, **kwargs)
 File "/home/undivided/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 58, in request
return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
File "/home/undivided/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 508, in request
resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
File "/home/undivided/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 618, in send
r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
File "/home/undivided/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 490, in send
raise ConnectionError(err, request=request)
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', RemoteDisconnected('Remote end closed connection without response',))
```

The request is being made like this:

```
res = requests.patch(
    url,
    json=mydata,
    headers={
        "If-Match": _etag,
        "Authorization": 'Bearer {}'.format(eve_token)
    }
)
```

The strange thing is, that all other request types to the same instance, including a GET to the exact same record, return properly. There are no errors that I can see in the Eve logs either.

The only possible complicating factor I can think of is that the eve application is deployed on a kubernetes cluster, but, as I said, all of the GETs/POSTs I have tried work as expected.

EDIT:

To add a further complicating factor, when I exec into my pod and try the request there, it succeeds, so it seems the problem is related to Kubernetes? Do I need to do something to enable HTTP PATCH on Kubernetes?

Comment: How it communicate inside, could you show your configurations of services and deployments

Answer (score 1):

I know this question is almost four years old, but if anyone stumbles upon this:

We had a very similar issue. PATCH requests from Python's `requests` to an application in our Kubernetes cluster failed with the `Remote end closed connection without response` message, while browser requests (and copying them to CURL and executing it from the CLI) worked fine.

Running the same Python script *inside* the cluster also worked fine (even from a different pod), so it seems like the issue is somewhere on the ingress (?) or at least not in the application.

After a bit of tinkering with the headers, we found out that the requests work if we remove the `Accept-Encoding` header from the python request by setting it to `None`:

```
head = {
  # ... other headers ...
  "Accept-Encoding": None,
}
r = requests.patch(url, json=payload, headers=head)
```

I'm not sure why this works, especially since CURL also works *with* the Accept-Encoding header.